# How to make a validation which not inside array list?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

i want to make and input that store all email inside array. however, the email must be **unique**. Here is the flow: user must list all email in order to proceed with invitation. Once invitation accepted by user, then their account created by the invited email.

here is my code:

```
public function invite()
    {

        $validatedData = $this->validate(
            ['email' => 'required|email|not_in:invitees.*'], //to filter the email is duplicated
            [
                'email.required' => 'The :attribute cannot be empty.',
                'email.email' => 'The :attribute format is not valid.',
            ],
            ['email' => 'Email Address']
        );
        

        $num = count($this->invitees);
        array_push($this->invitees, ['count' => $num, 'email' => $this->email]);
    }
```

the validation is 100% incorrect, can you help me?

Comment: If I understand, maybe you need a `Rule` to separate logic from the validation. You could create a Rule to validate that the email is not already on the list.

Comment: @Guille, can you explain more. Or, leave a link for reference

Comment: In this method you get one by one the emails or you receive a list of them at once?
If list, you need to filter duplicated data?

Comment: What is the field name you are using for emails?

Comment: `'email' => 'required|array'` and `'email.*' => 'required|email|not_in:invitees.email'` you can try this